# Are graphite intercalation compounds stable in water?

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I want to do an experiment with graphite sulfate, but I want to know if it will de-intercalate in a beaker of distilled water?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [*"Graphite sulphate – a precursor to graphene", Siegfried Eigler, Chem. Commun., 2015,51, 3162-3165*](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2015/cc/c4cc09381j):

> Graphite sulphate is used as a precursor to graphene for the first
>   time. The positively charged graphene layers react with water to yield
>   a processable graphene derivative.

This would seem to imply that it would indeed de-intercalate in a beaker of distilled water.